# My media query is not working when I add a resolution criteria, what can I do?

Tags: css, media-queries, screen-resolution

I have been developing a website for a competition I'm engaged in and to add some responsiveness to my website I decided to use media queries.

I tried using a variety of different codes to assign resolution to my media query but none of them work. I currently use a Mac Book Pro retina.

@media screen
    and (min-device-width: 1200px)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
    and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {

The code presented is not working, but when I delete the min-resolution it works nicely. I'm not sure if not having it will end up in some kind of problem in the future because every website that I consulted until now had some kind of min-resolution criteria.

Comment: "The code presented is not working" -> That's not really a useful description... *What* doesn't work?

Comment: the and between `(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) ` and `(min-resolution: 192dpi)` should be a comma. Like so, `(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi)` Check out this css tricks tutorial for more info https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue may be that the and between `(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)` and `(min-resolution: 192dpi)` must be turned into `(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi)`

I hope this helps!

Here's a css-tricks tutorial about retina display which may help: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It is working properly now.